# External Service through Component Bindings in Camel (Similar To Mule binding interface)

Tags: apache-camel, mule

I'm new in Apache Camel world and currently looking to understand how to use camel endpoints to Java interface methods. As per my requirement, I want to use an external service while the component(bean or transform or a process) is still processing the message. In Mule world - this is how it is implemented -

```
<component class="org.mule.examples.bindings.InvokerComponent">
    <binding interface="org.mule.examples.bindings.HelloInterface"
             method="sayHello">
        <cxf:outbound-endpoint
          address="http://myhost.com:81/services/HelloWeb?method=helloMethod"
          synchronous="true"/>
    </binding>
</component>
```

Here in this example - The binding causes the sayHello method in HelloInterface to call out to the external HelloWeb service when sayHello is called when InvokerComponent is in execution.

Currently, I'm reading about camel CXF-RS but not sure if this is way to implement this type of use case in Camel. Can anyone please help me or guide me to implement this? Any code example will be great. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Note that the implementation described is very uncommon these days. I think it is from many years ago. Currently using the Web Service Consumer for the client and APIKit for SOAP to implement servers are more modern methods that don't require Java classes.

Answer (score 0):

It’s quite an old unanswered question so sharing some ideas. You can use aggregator EIP for this situation.
The Aggregator from the EIP patterns allows you to combine a number of messages together into a single message.

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.13.x/eips/aggregate-eip.html
How to use Aggregator EIP using Spring and Apache Camel?
https://youtu.be/IdGuGGVv51Q